# Rotate text on go.Heatmap

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly, heatmap

I'm having a problem trying to figure out how to rotate the text on my heatmap. That dark-gray.white line running horic=zontally in the center of my heatmap is text that is overlaid on top of each other. I would like to rotate it 90 degrees so that it displays vertical, rather than horizontal. I have tried using textangle, add_annotation, and update_annotations with no luck. Does someone here know how this could be accomplished? Seems like it should be an easy thing to do but I am having a bit of trouble.

truck_df output:

```
                          Truck        Date  VIPR Data  Viriciti Data
3082  231_28_KAL_T2E_KIT_353604  2022-06-10       True          False
3083  231_28_KAL_T2E_KIT_353604  2022-06-11       True          False
3084  231_28_KAL_T2E_KIT_353604  2022-06-12       True          False
3085  231_28_KAL_T2E_KIT_353604  2022-06-13       True          False
3086  231_28_KAL_T2E_KIT_353604  2022-06-14       True          False
3087  231_28_KAL_T2E_KIT_353604  2022-06-15       True          False
3088  231_28_KAL_T2E_KIT_353604  2022-06-16       True          False
3089  231_28_KAL_T2E_KIT_353604  2022-06-17       True          False
3090  231_28_KAL_T2E_KIT_353604  2022-06-18       True          False
3091  231_28_KAL_T2E_KIT_353604  2022-06-19       True          False
3092  231_28_KAL_T2E_KIT_353604  2022-06-20       True          False
3093  231_28_KAL_T2E_KIT_353604  2022-06-21       True          False
3094  231_28_KAL_T2E_KIT_353604  2022-06-22      False          False
3095  231_28_KAL_T2E_KIT_353604  2022-06-23      False          False
3096  231_28_KAL_T2E_KIT_353604  2022-06-24      False          False
3097  231_28_KAL_T2E_KIT_353604  2022-06-25      False          False
3098  231_28_KAL_T2E_KIT_353604  2022-06-26      False          False
3099  231_28_KAL_T2E_KIT_353604  2022-06-27      False          False
3100  231_28_KAL_T2E_KIT_353604  2022-06-28      False          False
3101  231_28_KAL_T2E_KIT_353604  2022-06-29      False          False
3102  231_28_KAL_T2E_KIT_353604  2022-06-30      False          False
3103  231_28_KAL_T2E_KIT_353604  2022-07-01      False          False
3104  231_28_KAL_T2E_KIT_353604  2022-07-02      False          False
3105  231_28_KAL_T2E_KIT_353604  2022-07-03      False          False
3106  231_28_KAL_T2E_KIT_353604  2022-07-04      False          False
3107  231_28_KAL_T2E_KIT_353604  2022-07-05       True          False
3108  231_28_KAL_T2E_KIT_353604  2022-07-06       True          False
3109  231_28_KAL_T2E_KIT_353604  2022-07-07       True          False
3110  231_28_KAL_T2E_KIT_353604  2022-07-08       True          False
3111  231_28_KAL_T2E_KIT_353604  2022-07-09       True          False
3112  231_28_KAL_T2E_KIT_353604  2022-07-10       True          False
3113  231_28_KAL_T2E_KIT_353604  2022-07-11       True          False
3114  231_28_KAL_T2E_KIT_353604  2022-07-12       True          False
3115  231_28_KAL_T2E_KIT_353604  2022-07-13       True          False
3116  231_28_KAL_T2E_KIT_353604  2022-07-14       True          False
3117  231_28_KAL_T2E_KIT_353604  2022-07-15       True          False
3118  231_28_KAL_T2E_KIT_353604  2022-07-16       True          False
3119  231_28_KAL_T2E_KIT_353604  2022-07-17       True          False
3120  231_28_KAL_T2E_KIT_353604  2022-07-18       True          False
3121  231_28_KAL_T2E_KIT_353604  2022-07-19       True          False
3122  231_28_KAL_T2E_KIT_353604  2022-07-20       True          False
3123  231_28_KAL_T2E_KIT_353604  2022-07-21       True          False
3124  231_28_KAL_T2E_KIT_353604  2022-07-22      False          False
3125  231_28_KAL_T2E_KIT_353604  2022-07-23      False          False
3126  231_28_KAL_T2E_KIT_353604  2022-07-24       True          False
3127  231_28_KAL_T2E_KIT_353604  2022-07-25       True          False
3128  231_28_KAL_T2E_KIT_353604  2022-07-26       True          False
3129  231_28_KAL_T2E_KIT_353604  2022-07-27       True          False
3130  231_28_KAL_T2E_KIT_353604  2022-07-28       True          False
3131  231_28_KAL_T2E_KIT_353604  2022-07-29       True          False
3132  231_28_KAL_T2E_KIT_353604  2022-07-30       True          False
3133  231_28_KAL_T2E_KIT_353604  2022-07-31       True          False
3134  231_28_KAL_T2E_KIT_353604  2022-08-01       True          False
3135  231_28_KAL_T2E_KIT_353604  2022-08-02       True          False
3136  231_28_KAL_T2E_KIT_353604  2022-08-03       True          False
3137  231_28_KAL_T2E_KIT_353604  2022-08-04       True          False
3138  231_28_KAL_T2E_KIT_353604  2022-08-05       True          False
3139  231_28_KAL_T2E_KIT_353604  2022-08-06       True          False
3140  231_28_KAL_T2E_KIT_353604  2022-08-07       True          False
3141  231_28_KAL_T2E_KIT_353604  2022-08-08       True          False
3142  231_28_KAL_T2E_KIT_353604  2022-08-09       True          False
3143  231_28_KAL_T2E_KIT_353604  2022-08-10       True          False
3144  231_28_KAL_T2E_KIT_353604  2022-08-11       True          False
3145  231_28_KAL_T2E_KIT_353604  2022-08-12       True          False
3146  231_28_KAL_T2E_KIT_353604  2022-08-13       True          False
3147  231_28_KAL_T2E_KIT_353604  2022-08-14       True          False
3148  231_28_KAL_T2E_KIT_353604  2022-08-15       True          False
3149  231_28_KAL_T2E_KIT_353604  2022-08-16       True          False
3150  231_28_KAL_T2E_KIT_353604  2022-08-17       True          False
3151  231_28_KAL_T2E_KIT_353604  2022-08-18       True          False
3152  231_28_KAL_T2E_KIT_353604  2022-08-19       True          False
3153  231_28_KAL_T2E_KIT_353604  2022-08-20       True          False
3154  231_28_KAL_T2E_KIT_353604  2022-08-21       True          False
3155  231_28_KAL_T2E_KIT_353604  2022-08-22       True          False
3156  231_28_KAL_T2E_KIT_353604  2022-08-23       True          False
3157  231_28_KAL_T2E_KIT_353604  2022-08-24       True          False
3158  231_28_KAL_T2E_KIT_353604  2022-08-25       True          False
3159  231_28_KAL_T2E_KIT_353604  2022-08-26       True          False
3160  231_28_KAL_T2E_KIT_353604  2022-08-27       True          False
3161  231_28_KAL_T2E_KIT_353604  2022-08-28       True          False
3162  231_28_KAL_T2E_KIT_353604  2022-08-29      False          False
3163  231_28_KAL_T2E_KIT_353604  2022-08-30       True          False
3164  231_28_KAL_T2E_KIT_353604  2022-08-31      False          False
3165  231_28_KAL_T2E_KIT_353604  2022-09-01      False          False
3166  231_28_KAL_T2E_KIT_353604  2022-09-02      False          False
3167  231_28_KAL_T2E_KIT_353604  2022-09-03      False          False
3168  231_28_KAL_T2E_KIT_353604  2022-09-04      False          False
3169  231_28_KAL_T2E_KIT_353604  2022-09-05       True          False
3170  231_28_KAL_T2E_KIT_353604  2022-09-06      False          False
3171  231_28_KAL_T2E_KIT_353604  2022-09-07      False          False
3172  231_28_KAL_T2E_KIT_353604  2022-09-08      False          False
3173  231_28_KAL_T2E_KIT_353604  2022-09-09      False          False
3174  231_28_KAL_T2E_KIT_353604  2022-09-10      False          False
3175  231_28_KAL_T2E_KIT_353604  2022-09-11      False          False
3176  231_28_KAL_T2E_KIT_353604  2022-09-12      False          False
3177  231_28_KAL_T2E_KIT_353604  2022-09-13      False          False
3178  231_28_KAL_T2E_KIT_353604  2022-09-14      False          False
3179  231_28_KAL_T2E_KIT_353604  2022-09-15      False          False
3180  231_28_KAL_T2E_KIT_353604  2022-09-16       True          False
3181  231_28_KAL_T2E_KIT_353604  2022-09-17       True          False
3182  231_28_KAL_T2E_KIT_353604  2022-09-18       True          False
3183  231_28_KAL_T2E_KIT_353604  2022-09-19       True          False
3184  231_28_KAL_T2E_KIT_353604  2022-09-20       True          False
3185  231_28_KAL_T2E_KIT_353604  2022-09-21       True          False
3186  231_28_KAL_T2E_KIT_353604  2022-09-22      False          False
3187  231_28_KAL_T2E_KIT_353604  2022-09-23      False          False
3188  231_28_KAL_T2E_KIT_353604  2022-09-24      False          False
3189  231_28_KAL_T2E_KIT_353604  2022-09-25      False          False
3190  231_28_KAL_T2E_KIT_353604  2022-09-26       True          False
3191  231_28_KAL_T2E_KIT_353604  2022-09-27       True          False
3192  231_28_KAL_T2E_KIT_353604  2022-09-28       True          False
3193  231_28_KAL_T2E_KIT_353604  2022-09-29       True          False
3194  231_28_KAL_T2E_KIT_353604  2022-09-30       True          False
3195  231_28_KAL_T2E_KIT_353604  2022-10-01       True          False
3196  231_28_KAL_T2E_KIT_353604  2022-10-02       True          False
3197  231_28_KAL_T2E_KIT_353604  2022-10-03       True          False
3198  231_28_KAL_T2E_KIT_353604  2022-10-04       True          False
3199  231_28_KAL_T2E_KIT_353604  2022-10-05       True          False
3200  231_28_KAL_T2E_KIT_353604  2022-10-06      False          False
```

Code:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from datetime import date, datetime, timedelta
import dash
from dash import dcc, html
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State

try:
    # Subset the DataFrame to isolate the date column
    truck_date_df = truck_df['Date']
    # Convert the 'Date' column of the DataFrame into a list for the heatmap
    dates = list(truck_df['Date'])
    # Convert the 'vipr_bool' column of the DataFrame into a list
    vipr_bool = list(truck_df['VIPR Data'])
    # Convert 'False' to '0'
    vipr_bool = [0 if item == False else item for item in vipr_bool]
    # Convert 'True' to '1'
    vipr_bool = [1 if item == True else item for item in vipr_bool]
except Exception as e:
    print('-' * 40)
    print('update_plot ERROR')
    print(e)
    print('-' * 40)

try:
    # Filter the list to find the first 'True' value
    vipr_first_true = vipr_bool.index(1)
    # Reverse the list
    vipr_first_true_reversed = vipr_bool[::-1]
    # Find the index position of the last 'True'
    vipr_first_index_reversed = vipr_first_true_reversed.index(1)
    # Subtract 1 & the index position of the last 'True' from the length of 'vipr_bool' to obtain the index of the last 'True'
    vipr_last_true = len(vipr_bool)-1-vipr_first_index_reversed
    # Finds the row # and date of the first 'True' value
    vipr_low = truck_date_df[vipr_first_true:vipr_first_true+1]
    # Removes the index row # and isolates only the date
    vipr_low = vipr_low.iloc[0]
    # Finds the row # and date of the last 'True' value
    vipr_high = truck_date_df[vipr_last_true:vipr_last_true+1]
    # Removes the index row # and isolates only the date
    vipr_high = vipr_high.iloc[0]
    # Convert all '0' values to 'None', leaving the '1' values
    vipr_ones = [None if v!=1 else v for v in vipr_bool]
    # Convert all '1' values to 'None' leaving the '0' values
    vipr_zeros = [None if v!=0 else v for v in vipr_bool]
except Exception as e:
    print('VIPR')
    print(e)
    vipr_low = str(date(2014, 1, 1))
    vipr_high = str(date.today())
    vipr_ones = [0] * len(vipr_bool)
    vipr_zeros = [0] * len(vipr_bool)

try:
    # Assign vipr_low & vipr_high to low_range & high_range
    low_range = vipr_low
    high_range = vipr_high
except Exception as e:
    print(e)

try:
    # Initialize figure for plotly graph object
    fig = go.Figure()
except Exception as e:
    print('-' * 40)
    print('fig initialization ERROR')
    print(e)
    print('-' * 40)

try:
    # Add a trace to the heatmap containing all of the '1' values along with a legend marker
    fig.add_trace(go.Heatmap(
            x=truck_date_df,
            y=[''],
            z=[vipr_ones],
            text=[dates],
            texttemplate='%{text}',
            textfont={'size':10},
            name='= Data Found',
            colorscale=[(0.00, "#fde725"), (1.0, "#fde725")],
            showscale=False,
            showlegend=True,
            hovertemplate='<i><b>Date</i>: %{x}<extra></extra>'   
        )
    )

except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    
try:
    # Add a trace to the heatmap containing all of the '0' values along with a legend marker
    fig.add_trace(go.Heatmap(
            x=truck_date_df,
            y=[''],
            z=[vipr_zeros],
            name='= Data Not Found',
            colorscale=[(0.00, "#440154"), (1.0, "#440154")],
            showscale=False,
            showlegend=True,
            hovertemplate='<i><b>Date</i>: %{x}<extra></extra>'
        )
    )
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    # Add a trace to the heatmap containing all of the '0' values along with a legend marker
    fig.add_trace(go.Heatmap(
            x=truck_date_df,
            y=[''],
            z=[vipr_zeros],
            name='= Data Not Found',
            colorscale=[(0.00, "#440154"), (1.0, "#440154")],
            showscale=False,
            showlegend=True  
        )
    )

try:
    # Update the figure's x-axis/y-axis titles and the x-axis range
    fig.update_layout(title=go.layout.Title(text='<b>Data for Truck: </b>' + str(truck)),
                            xaxis_title='<b>Date</b>',
                            yaxis_title='',
                            xaxis_range=[low_range, high_range]
                            )
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    # Update the figure's x-axis/y-axis titles and the x-axis range
    fig.update_layout(title=go.layout.Title(text='<b>Data for Truck: </b>' + str(truck)),
                            xaxis_title='<b>Date</b>',
                            yaxis_title='',
                            xaxis_range=[date(2014, 1, 1), date(date.today())]
                            )

fig.update_layout(legend=dict(
    orientation='h',
    yanchor="bottom",
    y=1.02,
    xanchor="right",
    x=1
))

fig.show()
```

[image: Heatmap Output]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not have an exact memory. I don't think Express and Graph Objects support string rotation in string annotations. So use string rotation in the annotation function. I extracted some heatmap code from your entire code and added the string annotation code.

```
truck_date_df = truck_df['Date']
dates = list(truck_df['Date'])
vipr_bool = list(truck_df['VIPR Data'])
vipr_bool = [0 if item == False else item for item in vipr_bool]
vipr_bool = [1 if item == True else item for item in vipr_bool]
vipr_ones = [None if v!=1 else v for v in vipr_bool]

truck = '231_28_KAL_T2E_KIT_353604'

fig = go.Figure()

fig.add_trace(go.Heatmap(
        x=truck_date_df,
        y=[''],
        z=[vipr_ones],
        # text=[dates],
        # texttemplate='%{text}',
        # textfont={'size':10},
        name='= Data Found',
        colorscale=[(0.00, "#fde725"), (1.0, "#fde725")],
        showscale=False,
        showlegend=True,
        hovertemplate='<i><b>Date</i>: %{x}<extra></extra>'   
    )
)
fig.update_layout(annotations=[
    go.layout.Annotation(
        x=d,
        y=0.5,
        yref='paper',
        text=d,
        textangle=-90,
        align='center',
        showarrow=False) for d in dates])
        
fig.update_layout(title=go.layout.Title(text='<b>Data for Truck: </b>' + str(truck)),
                        xaxis_title='<b>Date</b>',
                        yaxis_title='',
                        xaxis_range=[low_range, high_range]
                        )

fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I just tried the script, and unfortunately, I have strange results in my plot. Namely, the text information somehow is collected at one point of the heatmap, but instead, it should be spread.

Comment: In my case, I did not have time series on the x-axis, and I had to change the scripts, so that the text will be aligned with the numeration. "fig.update_layout(annotations = [
    go.layout.Annotation(
        x=num,
        y=0.5,
        yref='paper',
        text=np.round(d, 2),
        textangle=-90,
        font=dict(color='white'),
        align='center',
        showarrow=False
    ) for d, num in zip(df_corr.values[0], [i for i in range(len(df_corr.values[0]))])
])"